# Why is a self-deleting, global Vulkan instance causing a segfault only when a layer is added?

Tags: c++, c++14, vulkan, raii

I am using a global `std::shared_ptr` to handle automatic deletion of my Vulkan `VkInstance`. The pointer has a custom deleter that calls `vkDestroyInstance` when it goes out of scope. Everything works as expected until I enable the `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation` layer at which point the `vkDestroyInstance` function causes a segfault.

I have added a minimal example below that produces the issue.

#### minimal.cpp

```cpp
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

// The global self deleting instance
std::shared_ptr<VkInstance> instance;

int main()
{
    std::vector<const char *> extensions = {VK_EXT_DEBUG_REPORT_EXTENSION_NAME};
    std::vector<const char *> layers = {};
    // Uncomment to cause segfault:
    // layers.emplace_back("VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation");

    VkApplicationInfo app_info = {};
    app_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    app_info.pApplicationName = "Wat";
    app_info.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
    app_info.pEngineName = "No Engine";
    app_info.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
    app_info.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_0;

    VkInstanceCreateInfo instance_info = {};
    instance_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    instance_info.pApplicationInfo = &app_info;
    instance_info.enabledExtensionCount =
        static_cast<uint32_t>(extensions.size());
    instance_info.ppEnabledExtensionNames = extensions.data();
    instance_info.enabledLayerCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(layers.size());
    instance_info.ppEnabledLayerNames = layers.data();

    // Handles auto deletion of the instance when it goes out of scope
    auto deleter = [](VkInstance *pInstance)
    {
        if (*pInstance)
        {
            vkDestroyInstance(*pInstance, nullptr);
            std::cout << "Deleted instance" << std::endl;
        }
        delete pInstance;
    };

    instance = std::shared_ptr<VkInstance>(new VkInstance(nullptr), deleter);
    if (vkCreateInstance(&instance_info, nullptr, instance.get()) != VK_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create a Vulkan instance" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    std::cout << "Created instance" << std::endl;

    // When the program exits, everything should clean up nicely?
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When running the above program as is, the output is what I would expect:

```sh
$ g++-7 -std=c++14 minimal.cpp -isystem $VULKAN_SDK/include -L$VULKAN_SDK/lib -lvulkan -o minimal
$ ./minimal 
Created instance
Deleted instance
$
```

However as soon as I add back the `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation` line:

```cpp
// Uncomment to cause segfault:
layers.emplace_back("VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation");
```

I get

```sh
$ g++-7 -std=c++14 minimal.cpp -isystem $VULKAN_SDK/include -L$VULKAN_SDK/lib -lvulkan -o minimal
$ ./minimal 
Created instance
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$
```

When run with `gdb` the backtrace shows the segfault occurring in the `VkDeleteInstance` function:

```sh
$ g++-7 -std=c++14 -g minimal.cpp -isystem $VULKAN_SDK/include -L$VULKAN_SDK/lib -lvulkan -o minimal
$ gdb -ex run ./minimal 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5) 7.11.1
...
Starting program: /my/path/stackoverflow/vulkan/minimal 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Created instance

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff24c4334 in threading::DestroyInstance(VkInstance_T*, VkAllocationCallbacks const*) () from /my/path/Vulkan/1.1.77.0/x86_64/lib/libVkLayer_threading.so
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff24c4334 in threading::DestroyInstance(VkInstance_T*, VkAllocationCallbacks const*) () from /my/path/Vulkan/1.1.77.0/x86_64/lib/libVkLayer_threading.so
#1  0x00007ffff7bad243 in vkDestroyInstance () from /my/path/Vulkan/1.1.77.0/x86_64/lib/libvulkan.so.1
#2  0x000000000040105c in <lambda(VkInstance_T**)>::operator()(VkInstance *) const (__closure=0x617c90, pInstance=0x617c60) at minimal.cpp:38
#3  0x000000000040199a in std::_Sp_counted_deleter<VkInstance_T**, main()::<lambda(VkInstance_T**)>, std::allocator<void>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_dispose(void) (this=0x617c80) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:470
#4  0x0000000000401ef0 in std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release (this=0x617c80) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:154
#5  0x0000000000401bc7 in std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count (this=0x6052d8 <instance+8>, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:684
#6  0x0000000000401b6a in std::__shared_ptr<VkInstance_T*, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr (this=0x6052d0 <instance>, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1123
#7  0x0000000000401b9c in std::shared_ptr<VkInstance_T*>::~shared_ptr (this=0x6052d0 <instance>, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr.h:93
#8  0x00007ffff724bff8 in __run_exit_handlers (status=0, listp=0x7ffff75d65f8 <__exit_funcs>, run_list_atexit=run_list_atexit@entry=true) at exit.c:82
#9  0x00007ffff724c045 in __GI_exit (status=<optimized out>) at exit.c:104
#10 0x00007ffff7232837 in __libc_start_main (main=0x40108c <main()>, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdcf8, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffdce8) at ../csu/libc-start.c:325
#11 0x0000000000400ed9 in _start ()
(gdb)
```

The problem can be fixed by using a local instance (inside the main function) instead of a global one so I'm thinking I might not fully understand some nuances of the Vulkan linker when using layers.

In my actual application I want to use a lazily instantiated static class to keep track of all my Vulkan objects and so I run into the same problem when the program exits.

### Setup

- g++: 7.3.0
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- Nvidia Driver: 390.67 (also tried 396)
- Vulkan SDK: 1.1.77.0 (also tried 1.1.73)
- GPU: GeForce GTX TITAN (Dual SLI if that matters?)

Comment: Been trying, but I'm unable to reproduce on MSVC 19.14.26429.4 x64 using Vulkan SDK 1.1.77.0.

Comment: Yeah works fine for me on windows as well. Maybe it's a linking issue or a driver bug on Linux.

Comment: Is the value of `*pInstance` in the deleter the same as it is after `vkCreateInstance`?

Comment: Yep. Same exact address for each.

Answer (score 5):

Global variables are a bad idea.  Their destruction is unordered relative to each other in most cases.

Clean up your state in main, not at static destruction time.  Simple objects that depend only on memory (a small step up from POD) and don't cross depend tend not to cause problems, but go any further and you enter a hornet's nest.

Your global shared ptr is being cleared and the destruction code run after some arbitrary global state within Vulkan is being cleared.  This is causing a segfault.  The interesting thing here isn't "why this segfault" but rather "how can I avoid this kind of segfault".  The answer to that is "stop using global state"; nothing else really works.

Comment: This was a minimal example created to illustrate a problem I found while creating a larger library. Even if I create explicit `init` and `destroy` functions, what prevents a user from attempting to create a similar global or static RAII object to do the same thing? Also, since asking the question I've also tested this example on Mac and Windows and they both work. Doesn't this imply I'm just getting lucky on other platforms?

Comment: @logan Nothing prevents a user from shooting themselves in the foot?  And yes, static destruction order is unspecified, so you can get lucky on one build and not on another, let alone switching platforms and compilers.

Comment: Very well. I'll document it then. Thanks.

Comment: The whole point of having a `VkInstance` (n.b. `VkAllocationCallbacks`) is not to have global state in Vulkan. It would be nice of layers to follow the same principle. If you figure this out, you should report it at [KhronosGroup/Vulkan-ValidationLayers](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-ValidationLayers/issues). It would help to run with symbols to get the offending line number in `threading.cpp`.